# Java - Updating static variables

Tags: java, static, static-members

I have two classes in java that need to run at the same time - A Crawler class ( that basically implements a web crawler, and keeps printing out urls as it encounters them ), and an Indexer class, which as of now, is supposed to simply print the urls crawled.

For this, my Indexer class has a Queue :

```
public static Queue<String> urls = new LinkedList();
```

And in the toVisit() function of my Crawler class, I have the following :

```
Indexer.urls.add( url ) // where url is a String
```

The Crawler is working totally fine, since it prints out all the urls that it has encountered, but for some reason, these urls do not get added to the Queue in my Indexer class. Any idea why this may be the case ?

The toVisit() method from Crawler.java is as follows :

```
public void visit(Page page) {
            int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();
            String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
            String domain = page.getWebURL().getDomain();
            String path = page.getWebURL().getPath();
            String subDomain = page.getWebURL().getSubDomain();
            String parentUrl = page.getWebURL().getParentUrl();

            System.out.println("Docid: " + docid);
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            System.out.println("Domain: '" + domain + "'");
            System.out.println("Sub-domain: '" + subDomain + "'");
            System.out.println("Path: '" + path + "'");
            System.out.println("Parent page: " + parentUrl);


            Indexer.urls.add( url );

            System.out.println("=============");
    }
```

Code from my Indexer class :

```
public static Queue<String> urls = new LinkedList();

public static void main( String[] args )
{
   while( urls.isEmpty() )
        {
            //System.out.println("Empty send queue");
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        }

        System.out.println( urls.poll() );

}
```

Comment: Please post the `toVisit()` method

Comment: are u running two threads ie: 1.Crawler thread 2.Indexer thread ?

Comment: or by chance are you running the Crawler in one classloader and the indexer in another one ? (eg. two different web applications?)

Comment: There may be a cross thread problem, can you put a sample code?

Comment: I am using Netbeans. So I am first running the main function of the Indexer class, and then the main function of the crawler class. I am using the sleep() function in Indexer in case the queue is empty.

Comment: so basically you're running the two classes separately ?

Comment: So you are running two different applications (processes) - So there is no chance to access the static variable of the other application.

Comment: agree with others. write a simple main which starts the 2 classes as a thread.

Comment: Ok, so if start both as threads in a single main(), then static variables can be accessed right ?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you to change your two main classes in order to implement Runnable and have a third class having just the main function which allocates the threads and starts them.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much :) I request you to please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: don't worry :), answer yourself and choose it as right one. have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I solved my problem by doing as suggested by BigMike. I implemented the Runnable interface in my two classes, and then ran those 2 classes as threads within the main function of a new third class.

Thanks everyone for all your help ! :)